# Biblatex : custom articles and books

Tags: biblatex

I recently started to use Biblatex and customize it a bit with some of your answers (A lot actually !!) but I'm still struggling with some of the features I like as I, sadly, don't understand much to most of the commands...

First, I'd like to show you what I've already done because there is probably a lot to say about it!

```
    \usepackage[language=french,sorting=nyt, hyperref=true,urldate=long,
    bibstyle=authortitle,citestyle=verbose,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}

    \addbibresource{These.bib}

    \defbibheading{bibliography}{
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
    \chapter{Bibliographie thématique}
    \markboth{\itshape Bibliographie thématique}{}
    }       

                        %******** Custom Bibliography *********

    \makeatletter
    \def\MKbibnamefirst#1{\expandafter\mkbibnamefirst@i#1..\@nil}
    \def\mkbibnamefirst@i#1.#2.#3\@nil{#1}

    \renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
      \ifuseprefix
        {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
         \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
         \ifblank{#3}{}{%
           \ifcapital
             {\mkbibnameprefix{{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}}%
           \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\addhighpenspace}}%
         \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
         \ifblank{#4}{}{\addlowpenspace\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
         \ifblank{#2}{}{\addlowpenspace\mkbibnamefirst{#2}}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
         \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
         \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
         \ifblank{#4}{}{\addlowpenspace\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
    %     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\addcomma}%
         \ifblank{#2}{}{\addlowpenspace\MKbibnamefirst{#2}}%
    %     \ifblank{#3}{}{\addlowpenspace\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}
    }}
    \makeatother

    % Commas as separators
    \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

    % Comma before and after journal volume
    \renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
      \printfield{volume}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
      \printfield{number}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \printfield{eid}}

    % Prefixes for journal volume and number
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}% volume of a journal
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% number of a journal

    % Comma before date; date not in parentheses
    \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
        \iffieldundef{issue}
          {\usebibmacro{date}}
          {\printfield{issue}%
           \setunit*{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
      \newunit}

    % Issue/date macros removed after journal number
    \renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
      \usebibmacro{journal}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \iffieldundef{series}
        {}
        {\newunit
         \printfield{series}%
         \setunit{\addspace}}%
      \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
      \newunit}

    % "In:" removed for articles; issue/date macros added after note+pages macro
    \DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
      \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
      \usebibmacro{begentry}%
      \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
      \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
      \usebibmacro{title}%
      \newunit
      \printlist{language}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{version}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
      \newunit
      \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
      \newunit
      \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
      \setunit{\addspace}
      \usebibmacro{issue+date}
      \setunit{\addcolon\space}
      \usebibmacro{issue}
      \newunit\newblock
      \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
        {\printfield{issn}}
        {}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
      \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
      \usebibmacro{pageref}%
      \usebibmacro{finentry}}

    \DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\mkbibquote{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

%Switch t. to vol.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{vol.~#1}

%Put ibid, op cit & co in italics
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph}

%Interligne entre les items Biblio
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{6pt}

%Change p. to pp.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
  pages = {pp\adddot},

    \begin{document}
    (...)
    \nocite{*}
    \begin{singlespace}
    \hyphenpenalty 10000
    \printbibheading
    \printbibliography[keyword=enreg,heading=subbibliography,title=Enregistrements audiovisuels des auditions]
    \printbibliography[keyword=justice,heading=subbibliography,title=Justice]
    \printbibliography[keyword=management,heading=subbibliography,title=Management et modernisation]
    \printbibliography[keyword=visio,heading=subbibliography,title=Visioconférence]
    \end{singlespace}
    \end{document}
```

I'd like to modify the appearance of my articles and books :

**FOR ARTICLES :**
I'm getting :
LASTNAME Firstname, « Title », *Journal*, Vol. 10, no 3, pp. 56 – 79, month year.
And I'd like :
LASTNAME Firstname, « Title », *Journal*, month year, vol. 10, no 3, pp. 56 – 79.
Which means:
- Get the month year block after the journal

**FOR BOOKS :**
I'm getting :
LASTNAME Firstname, «*Title*», Address : Publisher, year, 271 p.
And I'd like :
LASTNAME Firstname, «*Title*», Publisher, Address, year, 271 p.
Which means:
- Get the year after the adress
- Get in order the publisher separated from the adress with a comma

I realise that it's a lot to ask!! But I couldn't get nowhere with my experimentations and I'm lacking time to do more sad failures!!

Tks very much in advance for any help, or comment on my present modifications !
;-)

Comment: @Doompa: This is a big list to look at, and I won't promise anything. But one question: Why don't you choose an `authortitle` style instead of `authoryear`?

Comment: @ Lockstep : Tkx for not being scared by all those requests!! Well... I actually never really tought about it... as no style fits what I'd like... But you're right, it's better! i'm getting the year without brackets, the title in italics with books, and almost the total pages! I'm changing this right now! See how that long list of requests is now almost short?! No?

Comment: @Doompa: You should edit your question so that it reflects the "short list of requests". Besides that, please tell what `\DeclareRangeCommands{\pno\ppno}` does (or should do).

Comment: @ Lockstep : I've edited my question! Besides, how shameful do you think it is to have to write that I can't even remember what it was for..., but was to scared to delete it and miss it later?

Comment: @Doompa: It's only shameful if you don't add comments in your code from now on. ;-)

Comment: @ Lockstep : I've edited my question! Thx very much for this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer will be a work in progress, and it will quite possibly not cover all requests. That said, do the following:

- Delete the code line `\DeclareRangeCommands{\pno\ppno}`;
- Add the code line `\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\mkbibquote{\mkbibemph{#1}}}`;
- Add the package option `dateabbrev=false`.

One way to switch from "t." to "vol." for articles would be to choose `language=english`. Is that what you want? Please explain.

EDIT: For @book entries, use the `pagetotal` field instead of the `pages` field.

EDIT 2: For @book & friends, add the following to your preamble:

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

To be consistent, you should also change the bibmacros `institution+location+date` and `organization+location+date` along these lines. (The originals are located in `standard.bbx`.)

EDIT 3: For @article, the following seems to work at first glance (and I didn't bother to check it thouroughly):

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \newunit}
```

@Doompa: That's it for now. If your style still needs finetuning, please add any requests to your original question (your edits became quite confusing for me). Also think about *why* you want a particular change.

Comment: I've adopted your modifications but couldn't comment properly as you haven't told me what it was for! I'm joking those where easy! It's definetely going in the right direction! I've edited my question. For the "t." to "vol.", it's interesting because it also get me my pages like I want them, but the change of language cause me other problems as it switch the number field in a wrong way, and also I get the months in english and need them in french! Thx for your involvement dear Lockstep!

Comment: @ Lockstep : It's perfect!!! I really want to thank you for all your efforts as I know I had a lot of requests!

Comment: @ Lockstep : Done!

Answer (score 0):

For @ARTICLES, I found how to transform the "t." to "vol." :

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol.~#1\addcomma}
```

Today is my lucky day! I've just found the answer to my problem  with pages :
For @ARTICLES, to switch p. to pp. :

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
  pages = {pp\adddot},
}
```

Comment: As I didn't want Lockstep to be doing all the work! Well of course, I didn't invented it and copied it loosely... but it seems to work!! ;-)

Comment: @Doompa: What happens if you drop `\addcomma`? biblatex should take care about the punctuation with macros like `\newunit\newblock`.

Comment: @ Lockstep : You're right the \addcomma is not needed ! How awesome it would be to actually understand what I'm doing!! :-)

Comment: Well, I was too excited... My command change the p. to pp. but also for the @BOOK... which means that my total pages are written 271 pp. Which is not okay!! Pfff...

Comment: @Doompa: Why do you want to change the plural form, *but only in some cases?*

Comment: @ Lockstep : Well, actually it's just the requirements in my specialty! For @articles I've got to have pp. 45 - 67 (or few pages) or p. 45 (for only one page) but for @books i've got to stay with the totalpages field like 271 p. I've tried : \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{pp\adddot~#1} which is quite nice because It allows me to respect the difference between Books and Articles, unlike my first try, but instead I'm getting pp. 34 if the article is only one page long... I've got only a few in my bibliography, but it looks terrible!